# Where can I find terms and expressions related to mathematics?

Tags: resources

If I was to, for example, do a *prelego* during a *kongreso* about math, I would need to expand my vocabulary quite alot. Is there a collection of useful terms and expressions somewhere? Here are some examples:

> - multilplied by ...
> - divided by ...
> - the squareroot of ...
> - expression
> - equation
> - variables
> - raised to the power of ...
> - axis
> - coordinates
> - derivative
> - function

Answer (score 3):

A very good resource for mathematical terms in Esperanto is the [Matematika Vortaro kaj Oklingva Leksikono](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=7069) by Marc Bavant. The author of this book also edited the [mathematical terms and definitions in ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/inx/fx_MAT.html), so ReVo is practically an equally good resource.

Answer (score 1):

For nouns, you can look them up in the English version of Wikipedia, and then, in the sidebar, select the Esperanto version of Wikipedia to get the Esperanto translation.

I am creating an Esperanto-based front-end for Wikipedia that features extensive cross-referencing, which you might wish to use for this purpose. For the nouns on your list, here are links to this Esperanto-based front-end of mine:

[axis](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/temo-axis.html)

[coordinates](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/temo-coordinates.html)

[derivative](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/temo-derivative.html)

[equation](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/folder-equation.html)

[expression](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/temo-expression.html)

[function](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/folder-function.html)

[square root](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/vorto-square-root.html)

[variables](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/temo-variables.html)

For the phrases, I suggest consulting [Benson](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/reference-peter-benson.html) / [Wells](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/reference-john-wells.html) / [Vikivortaro](https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vortaro_angla-Esperanta), although none of them treat the full phrases that you have listed (and I count it as a defect in them that they don’t).

Answer (score 1):

You can search here: http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/

Here are some purely in Esperanto:
http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/inx/fx_MAT.html

Answer (score -1):

I would start by checking a good bilingual dictionary. PIV (vortaro.net) would also be a good source.

A google search for *matematiko* and *terminaro* pulled up a few promising results, including this one.

https://books.google.com/books/about/Matematiko_terminaro_kaj_krestomatio.html?id=m2gxAQAAMAAJ (Which as Marcos pointed out is old - but it's not the only choice. For specialist terms, it always makes sense to cross reference.)

If you're having trouble with a particular term or passage, I would suggest working directly with someone who has experience in this area. If you like, I could suggest someone by private message.

Comment: Pardon my OT comment but how do you send a private message here?? That'd be so useful at times. I've been around SE/SO for over 4 years and the closest I've seen is opening a chat room (and I'd have trouble finding even that).

Comment: For mathematical terms, ReVo (reta-vortaro.de) is better than PIV (vortaro.net). Also the "Matematika terminaro" that you found is very old, whereas the newer resource by Marc Bavant mentioned in my answer is up to date.

Comment: There is no private messaging on SE. That is apparently by design. If anybody was interested in reaching my via private message, I'm in the telegram group for SE and also pretty easy to find on line - FB, Duolingo, YouTube, and so on.